# Gitlab Jira integration

Tags: jira, gitlab

[image]I have Gitlab CE version 8.3 which is integrated with Jira. I am an admin user for Gitlab & have admin rights to the project in Jira. While pushing any commit to Gitlab with reference to issue id of jira creates successful link for it but no comments get posted from gitlab to jira. What could be the issue here?
My configurations also seem to be correct since the link between jira & gitlab is fine.

Comment: Is this worked for you?

Answer (score 5):

There's usually one more step you need to deal with in GitLab config, and that's setting appropriate "JIRA issue transition" value (which will trigger these comments).

In case you use custom workflows (but even if you don't) you need to double check whether value for "JIRA issue transition" specified under Gitlab's Services (Settings > Services > JIRA) matches transition ID in your JIRA workflow ([take a look at this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/img/jira_workflow_screenshot.png)).

More info is available [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/project_services/jira.html#configuring-gitlab).

"It is the ID of a transition that moves issues to a closed state. You can find this number under the JIRA workflow administration (Administration > Issues > Workflows) by selecting View under Operations of the desired workflow of your project. The ID of each state can be found inside the parenthesis of each transition name under the Transitions (id) column (see screenshot). By default, this ID is set to 2."

Comment: I have got jira transiiton value set to "2" in Gitlab. And in Jira I have got something like the above image in asked question. SO, where do I need to make this change of transition value ?

Comment: What is the transition ID you have in JIRA for transition "Closed" (number in brackets)? In the upper case it's 151 (take a look at the screenshot), and this value should be set in GitLab instead of 2. So, check your exact transition ID in JIRA (3rd column in the screenshot) and update GitLab setting with it. Check out Gitlab documentation link I've sent for a reference.

Comment: (The screenshot that you attached is cut off so it doesn't show the crucial part - Closed state, and transition ID for "Closed" in that last row.)

Comment: I followed your suggestion & added the value of transition "Closed" as 711 in Jira to Gitlab but still comments are not getting posted. Is there anything else that can be checked?

Comment: It's sort of blind debugging, but let's try several things. - "Make sure that the user you set up for GitLab to communicate with JIRA has the correct access permission to post comments on a ticket and to also transition the ticket, if you'd like GitLab to also take care of closing them." - Make sure you reference JIRA issue correctly in your git commit messages. If that doesn't solve it either, I'd literally go step by step through http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/project_services/jira.html#configuring-gitlab and check whether there are any deviations. Hope this helps.